# jenkins, how to run multiple remote jobs without stopping on failure

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins job that I'm using to aggregate the execution of multiple other jobs that only perform testing. Because they are testing, I want all the jobs to run regardless of any failures. I do want to keep track of wether or not there has been a failure so that I can set the end result to FAILURE rather than SUCCESS if need be.
At the moment I am calling 1 remote job via bash script and jenkins-cli. I have a 2nd child job that is local, so I'm using "trigger/call builds on other jobs" build step to run that one.
Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use build_flow-plugin it is easy, if you use pipeline it is possible too but can't give you example. Have to look it up if that is the case.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin:

```
    def result = SUCCESS
    ignore(FAILURE){
      def job1 = build('job1')
      result = job1.result.combine(result)
    }
    ignore(FAILURE){
       def job2 = build('job2')
       result = job1.result.combine(result)
    }

build.result = result.combine(build.result)
```

http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Result.html